# SSRS: A severe error has occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm developing an SSRS 2008 report using stored procs.  Previously this report was running successfully.  Now, however, these stored procs still run but when I run this report I get the following error:

A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.  Operation cancelled by user.

What is the cause of this and how can I debug?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the report is timing out.  Try setting the Report Execution Timeout to a longer value.

Take a look at this MSDN link: [Setting Time-out Values for Report Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155782%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

thanks, Alison.  I figured this out now.  I just started with the smallest element and gradually rebuilt my report until I found the cause...

Comment: And what was the cause?  You should share your answer with everyone else.